# SQL Profiler not showing inserts/deletes/updates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, entity-framework, sql-server-profiler

When I run the profiler while running my application, it only seems to show SELECTs, not INSERTs or anything that changes the database. Yet my database is being updated, so those commands must be being executed. What do I have to do to get it to show updates? (I am using Entity Framework, btw, if that might make a difference.)

Comment: Can you list which Profiler events you are tracking? Nothing's filtered, right?

Answer (score 18):

I figured out how to do it - I had to select `SQL:StmtStarting` and `SP:StmtStarting`, not just `SQL:BatchStarting` or `SP:Starting`.

Not sure what the differences are, but the inserts/deletes, etc. It showed up when I included those events.

Comment: It looks like the key is also selecting the SPs.  Even though we don't use stored procedures, our inserts/updates etc only show up if we turn on SP.  Not sure why, but it works.